# Almost surely convergence for independent random variables and bounded real sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Stumbled upon an exercise in my probability course which was given a couple of years ago as an assignment problem and was trying to solve it. However, I am struggling a bit with probability theory (especially the convergence part and characteristic functions part of the course) and thus I have no idea how to solve this.

Problem. Suppose we have $X_{2}, X_{3}, \ldots$ independent random variables and $E[X_{1}] = 1$. Let $y_{n}$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers. Show that we have $\frac{1}{n} \sum^{n}_{j = 1} y_{j} \longrightarrow{} 1$ if and only if $\frac{1}{n} \sum^{n}_{j = 2} y_{j} X_{j} \longrightarrow 1,$ a.s.

Comment: Your bounds for summation are $j=1$ to $n$ and $j=2$ to $n$ while your variables are in terms of $k$. You might want to correct that. Also, you have $X_2,X_3,\ldots$ independent random variables with $\mathbb E[X_1]=1$ - does the sequence start at $2$ or at $1$?

Comment: The forward part is a generalisation of the strong law, so I would expect a similar approach.

Comment: @Math1000 I copied the problem statement from the old assignment. So I cannot answer your question.

Comment: @copper.hat thanks for the hint. Will look into that later.

Comment: I am assuming something minimal like $E|X_1| < \infty$. It is implicit in $E X_1 = 1$ but usually stated explicitly.

Comment: @copper.hat Here the $X_i$ are not assumed to be i.i.d. so we should have the assumption that $\mathbb E[|X_i|]<\infty $and $\mathbb E[X_i]=1$ for all $i$, correct?

Comment: I would presume that they are iid. given the number of omissions in the question.

Comment: But it is certainly incumbent on the OP to clarify the level & generality of the question.

Comment: you can prove it using a non iid SLLN for $E[X_1^2] <\infty$, because $E[y_j(X_j-1)] = 0$

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst what does SLLN stand for? I presume that LLN stands for law of large numbers? EDIT: nvm it stands for Strong law of large numbers.

Comment: @Math1000 So I found the same question in an old exam with the following statement: Let $X_{n}$, $n \geq 2$ be independent r.v.s and $E[X_{1}] = 1$ and $\{ a_{n} \}$ are bounded real numbers, then we have $\frac{1}{n} \sum^{n}_{k = 1} a_{k} \rightarrow 1 \iff \frac{1}{n} \sum^{n}_{k = 2} a_{k}X_{k} \overset{a. s}{\longrightarrow} 1$.

Comment: @copper.hat These are all the given information and the level of generality on the problem.

Comment: I imagine that you need $E X_k = 1$ for $k=1,2,...$.

Comment: @copper.hat ok. let us assume that and whatever seems reasonable. Do I have to use the strong law of large numbers now or how does this work?

Comment: I would imagine so, if you were to choose $y_k =1$ for all $k$ you need a strong law to conclude that the average converges ae.